# Using default as a default value for a nullable value type parameter does not assign null

Tags: c#, default, roslyn, specifications

The post [default value expressions (C# programming guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/default-value-expressions#default-literal-and-type-inference) by microsoft explains the usage and behaviour of `default(T)`. The behaviour was (and still is) as follows:

```
var x = default(uint?);
Assert.IsNull(x); // ok

uint? y = default;
Assert.IsNull(y); // ok
```

The post then continues and explains the usage and behaviour of `default` ([default literal and type inference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/default-value-expressions#default-literal-and-type-inference)) which was introduced in C# 7.1. Before C# 7.1 we did:

```
void BeforeCsharp7_1(uint? z = default(uint?))
{
   Assert.IsNull(z); // ok
}
```

With C# 7.1 we can do:

```
void WithCsharp7_1(uint? z = default)
{
   Assert.IsNull(z); // Fail, expected null but was 0
}
```

You might be surprised to read that the last snipped will not assert because the parameter `z` equals `0`. After upgrading my project to C# 7.1  Visual Studio kept telling me that `default(uint?)` could be simplified to `default` which then results in this very different behaviour. This must be a bug in Visual Studio.

**Is this also a bug in the C# Specification / Roslyn or is this by design?**

Comment: It was a bug in Roslyn. It's fixed now: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/970 (Basically you should upgrade your VS2017 installation to the latest version.)

Comment: @DaisyShipton Could you add this as the answer so that I can accept it? I am currently checking if C# 7.2 solves this issue (as explained in the link you posted) and will report back.

Comment: Updating Visual Studio 2017 to version 15.7.6 solves the issue. No language update required. (It should already work for version 15.5+)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a [bug in Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/970) which has now been fixed in VS15.5 / .NET Core SDK 2.1.200 and above. Yes, the default literal should indeed return `null` for nullable value types.